# Assign Jquery List value to text button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Assign Jquery Variable(caintains Mobile number and cantact name) to text button..
I have a list where the list elements are iterated in jsp,using jquery and math.random getting the random item(contains mobile_num and name)while assigning the value to text box only one value is getting assigned...here how the code looks like...

```
<ul><s:iterator value="CantactList"> <li> <s:property value="name"/>
<s:property value="Mobile Number"/><li></s:iterator></ul>
```

and in jQuery...

```
$form = $("<form action="+"xyz"+"></form>");
$form.append('<input type="text" value='+item+' name="Cantact"/>');
```

if i use lable or alert(item) works fine....after executing this code i inspect the input box..
where the code looks like this..

```
<input type="text" 9333333="" value="Jhon" name="Cantact"/>
```

not able to understand why this happening..any advices..??

Comment: __9333333__ is the value of item?

Comment: value of item looks like (jhon 9333333)caintains on <li> item

Comment: Cna you expand a bit what do you mean with your previous comment?

Comment: Yea sure...<s:iterator value="ContactList> caintains a list of contacts..like Mobile Number and name of person ( <s:property value="name"/> holds the name,<s:property value="Mobile Num/> Holds Mobile Number so the li looks like <li>Jhon 933333</li> if i assign this <li> value to text box its looks like 93333="" value="Jhon"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try to change this

```
$form = $("<form action="+"xyz"+"></form>");  
$form.append('<input type="text" value='+item+' name="Cantact"/>');
```

to

```
$form = $('<form action="xyz"></form>'); // not so important
$form.append('<input type="text" value="'+item+'" name="Cantact"/>'); //this is more important
```

Comment: you are welcome! I hope you see the difference when to use doubble- and single-quotes and how to use both.. happy coding!